# Vault loading too late

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft, bukkit, bukkit-vault

My Plugin is loading before Vault, even tho I added a depend/load-after into the plugin.yml

I tried **depend**, **softdepend** and **loadbefore**. I even tried downgrading the on the server used version of Vault.

**I tried even loadbefore without depend and the other way around.**

My plugins.yml

```yaml
name: TrainsaPlugin
version: ${project.version}
main: de.gamingcraft.trainsa.TrainsaPlugin

(...)

loadbefore:
  - Vault

depend:
  - Vault

commands: (...)
```

My Main Class:

```java
public final class TrainsaPlugin extends JavaPlugin {

    (...)

    public static Economy econ = null;
    public static Permission perms = null;
    public static Chat chat = null;


    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        (...)

        if (!setupEconomy() ) {
            System.out.println("Disabled due to no Vault dependency found!");
            getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
            return;
        }
        setupPermissions();
        setupChat();
    }

    private boolean setupEconomy() {
        if (getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Vault") == null) {
            return false;
        }
        RegisteredServiceProvider<Economy> rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Economy.class);
        if (rsp == null) {
            return false;
        }
        econ = rsp.getProvider();
        return econ != null;
    }

    private boolean setupChat() {
        RegisteredServiceProvider<Chat> rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Chat.class);
        chat = rsp.getProvider();
        return chat != null;
    }

    private boolean setupPermissions() {
        RegisteredServiceProvider<Permission> rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Permission.class);
        perms = rsp.getProvider();
        return perms != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
    }

    (...)
}
```

The Log

```
[22:35:43 INFO]: [TrainsaPlugin] Disabling TrainsaPlugin v1.0
(...)
[22:35:43 INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[22:35:43 INFO]: Done (1,912s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
[22:35:43 INFO]: [Vault] Checking for Updates ...
```

I know, that my main-class disables my plugin when Vault is not found and i want that because it's essential at the moment.

TL;DR: My problem is, that Vault loads too late.

Comment: Can you attach the error you are getting?

Comment: Do you use any other plugins?

Comment: I use NPCLib and SmartInvs

Comment: And they are both depends not loadbefores right? If this is the case then using other plugins shouldn't matter.

Comment: both aren't even mentioned in the plugins.yml and still work.
Edit: i know, not good behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```xml
<scope>provided</scope>
```

to every dependency, that was a plugin in the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

To your plugin.yml add `depend: [Vault]`

For more info see [this](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_YAML)

Answer (score 0):

You added vault to `loadbefore`, which makes your plugin load before vault. If you want vault to load before your plugin, use `depend: [Vault,someOtherPlugin,someOtherPlugin,etc]`.

Comment: tried that, read the question. doesn't work.

Comment: The behaviour is inconsistent if you have both loadbefore and depend. It is not clear that you have tried it without loadbefore. Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: i tried to both, without loadbefore and without depend.

Comment: What he is trying to say is, that he already tried to do it with just depend: [Vault] but it did not work.

Comment: Strange. Can anyone reproduce it? Doesn't seem to be happening on my end. Maybe try using the [] list format instead of yours, but both should work. (and probably neither does)

Comment: tried that aswell. didn't work :/ and please stop commenting, redi.

Comment: I just created a blank new Java project and replicated your steps. It does not work